# Pelle, Haut, Schale – Was denn jetzt?

Tags: meaning

Vor ein paar Tagen geriet ich mit meinen Kollegen in eine Diskussion über Kartoffeln.

Der eine meinte: "Kartoffeln haben eine Haut"
Ich entgegnete: "Aber man schält sie doch. Ergo haben sie eine Schale."
Da meinte der Dritte: "Und was ist dann mit Pellkartoffeln?"

Es gibt ja einige eindeutige Beispiele:

```
Äpfel – Schale
Birnen – Schale
Nüsse – Schale
Pfirsiche – Haut
usw.
```

Äpfel und Birnen werden geschält, Tomaten (z. B. für Konserven) gehäutet und Nüsse geknackt.

Damit unterteilt sich Schale ja wieder. In eine zum Knacken und eine andere zum Schälen.

Also: Was ist – bei pflanzlichen Nahrungsmitteln – der Unterschied zwischen Haut, Pelle und Schale – zum Schälen –, und was haben Kartoffeln?

Comment: So eindeutig finde ich die Beispiele nicht alle. Für mich haben vielleicht Pfirsiche eine Haut, aber sicher nicht Tomaten. Bei _Pelle_ habe ich Regionalismusverdacht.

Comment: @chirlu was haben tomaten denn dann?? und das Kartoffelproblem bleibt ja bestehen... außerdem kann man über all in Deutschland *"jemandem auf die Pelle rücken"* oder etwa nicht?

Comment: Tomaten haben **natürlich** eine Schale. :-)

Comment: Mal abgesehen von "jemanden auf die Pelle rücken" und "Pellkartoffeln" verwende ich das Wort "Pelle" gar nicht. Es gilt als norddeutsch, und da ich oberhalb der unsichtbaren Linie wohne, sollte es zu meinem Sprachgebrauch dennoch gehören. Pelle ist definiert als dünne Haut. Schale ist der gängige Name für jegliches Obst u. Gemüse, einschließlich Pfirsich und Tomate. Haut ist bei manchen Obstsorten auch sehr gängig, kann aber auf jegliches Obst u. Gemüse angewendet werden. Pelle wird nur wenig und für bestimmte Produkte verwendet. Und die Vitamine liegen direkt under der Haut - äh Schale ;)

Comment: Habe zwischenzeitlich im _Variantenwörterbuch_ nachschlagen können. Tatsächlich ist _pellen_ regional (im wesentlichen nördlich der Mainlinie). Es gibt auch eine Reihe von Alternativbezeichnungen zu _Pellkartoffeln_, z.B. _geschwellte Kartoffeln_ (Schweiz) und _Erdäpfel in der Montur_ (Österreich). Als Vertreter des nördlichen Südwesten verwende ich persönlich zwar _Pellkartoffeln_ als festen Begriff, die Wörter _pellen_ und _Pelle_ aber nicht. _Häuten_ erscheint mir als Fachbegriff der Kochsprache. Ich _schäle_ alles.

Comment: @Em1: Könntest du eine Bananenschale als Haut bezeichnen?

Comment: @chirlu OK, in dem Punkt hätte ich etwas präziser sein müssen. Theoretisch gesehen ist das schon irgendwie eine Haut. Aber es gibt einen entscheidenen Unterschied. Du isst die Schale nicht mit. Ich würde auch bei Mandarinen aus dem Grund nicht von *Haut*, sondern nur von *Schale* sprechen. Ich *schäle* imho übrigens auch keine Banane. Wenn ich *schäle* habe ich ein Messer o.ä. in der Hand ;)

Comment: @Em1: Schon interessant, diese sprachlichen Unterschiede. Ich kann sehr gut ohne Hilfsmittel schälen; es gibt auch viele Treffer bei Google für "Banane schälen" (oben/unten anfangen). Von _Haut_ würde ich selbst sowieso nicht sprechen, aber bei so etwas Dickem wie Bananenschale finde ich den Begriff direkt unangemessen. - Wie nennst du es denn, wenn du Bananen, äh, von ihrer nicht genießbaren Hülle trennst?

Comment: @chirlu Als kleines Kind habe ich immer gesagt: "Kannst du die Banane aufmachen." oder "Ich kann die blöde Banane nicht öffnen." Ich denke, dass ich das auch heutzutage noch so sagen würde, aber da ich es nicht mehr so kommunizieren muss, habe ich wohl keinen aktiven Ausdruck dafür.

Comment: @chirlu: Ich schäle auch alles. Gerade bei dicken (und/oder ungenießbaren) Schalen finde ich "Haut" ziemlich seltsam. Pellkartoffeln kenne ich nur als solche, aber mir kommt in Bezug auf "Pelle" hauptsächlich "Wurstpelle" in den Sinn.

Comment: Auf der sprichwörtlichen Bananenschale rutscht man aus. Pelle kenne ich auch eher von der Wurstpelle, wobei ich bei Pellkartoffeln die Kartoffelschale abpelle. Das Haut gesagt wird, wenn man es mitisst, war auch mein erster Verdacht, womit ich nicht sagen will, dass ich Frauen esse. Jene haben aber sporadisch eine Orangenhaut, die Orangen selbst aber nicht haben, was kurz irritierend wirken kann. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In der Biologie sind Schalen fest bis hart und undurchlässig. Haut ist oft dünn, weich und transparent. Pelle ist ein norddeutsch regionaler Begriff, der sich heute durch verschiedene Dialekte zieht und teilweise mit ganz bestimmten Begriffen (z.B. Kartoffel, Ei) verbunden wird, mit einer gewissen Unschärfe in Bezug auf die Unterscheidung zwischen Schale und Haut, jedoch figurativ mehr im Sinne von Haut.

Bei Kartoffeln nennt man die Schale das dick Abgeschnittene, Pelle wird in der Regel die eigentliche (dunkle) Schicht genannt, die bei Zubereitung als Pellkartoffeln hautartig abgezogen werden kann.

Answer (score 0):

Das normale Wort bei Kartoffeln ist Schale. Pelle ist norddeutsch.
Duden sagt: Gebrauch landschaftlich, besonders norddeutsch.

http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Pelle